# Unlike Item in Chatter API: "HTTP Method DELETE not allowed"

Tags: rest-api, chatter, delete

I'm trying to do an "unlike" on a chatter feed item through REST. I can't find the official documentation on how to do this, but per posts in different [forums](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000099lKIAQ) = we simply change the method to "DELETE".

Changing to "DELETE" comes back with the error:

Although it comes back with error:

"HTTP Method DELETE not allowed"

Can someone tell me how to delete a like / or "unlike" an item in a Chatter feed through REST? Thx

Comment: If i understand the documetnation correctly, [Likes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_responses_like_page.htm) is an Array, so you will have to access its values and remove accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, I was able to "delete" the actual like. Once you "like" an item, it returns the id of the like, as well as the "url":

`/services/data/%version%/chatter/likes/%likesId%;`

[image]

I was able to hit this url with method "DELETE" - and deletes the like